# How to change path of socket.io in socket.io.slim.js

Tags: html, socket.io, easyrtc

I am using socket.io for multiuser experience in one of our metaverse projects. We have deployed the code in a https server and after deploying the multiuser experience collapsed. When check for errors, we have found the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IP5S.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7unz.png)

we need to change the path of Url for where it needs to look for socket.io.

Can someone suggest any ideas for changing this path?

Answer (score 1):

This usually means one of 2 things:

1. the socket.io server is not running
2. the socket.io server is running on a different place

Make sure socket.io is using the HTTPS server, not the HTTP one, and the client is connecting to the correct domain.